# Intersection between line & polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a linestrings consist of 2 vertices. I want to get all lines that don't intersects with any polygons on the way. In my example: blue line Not intersects - only touches some polygons, but black line although touches with some polygon, it also intersects another. So in conclusion the result is only blue line.

[image]

What I did:

```
 SELECT lines.geom
 FROM lines, polygons
 WHERE ST_Intersects(lines.geom, polygons.geom) = false 
       AND
       ST_Touches(lines.geom, polygons.geom) = true;
```

The `ST_Touches` seems to work - I guess because the representation of the line-string consist of the vertex that really touches the polygon.

The `ST_Intersects` not working - The result is that there is no even 1 line that intersect any polygon.

So what I started to thinking: Maybe because in the space where the line intersect polygon - ain't any 'real' representation of the line-string: Because what is line-string? 2 vertices both outside the polygon...

Whats going on? I thought that GEO-DB should deal exactly with this kind of challenges and 'knows' what spatially intersection is...

---

Altough I don't know how to do this (because `ST_Segmentize` not worked for me from some reason) I prefer not to overcome this issue with just 'breaking' the line-string to more elements such that with high probability some vertex would be inside the polygon.

Comment: Your belief of the meaning of ST_Intersects is wrong. When touches=true also intersects=true. Intersects means the same as "not disjoint" http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html.

Comment: You right, see my self answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user30184 noted, you have to use ST_Crosses() instead of ST_Intersects().

Additional, your expression works on one line compared to one polygon only: The black line touches Polygon 1 and doesn't cross Polygon 1. In more detail:

SELECT x FROM line, polygons WHERE ...

means: Build a case from every pair of a line and a polygon, so number of cases is n_lines x n_polygons. Do the WHERE clause for every case and keep cases where it is true. Result: blue line, P1: false, blue line, P2: true, black line, P1: true, black line, P2: false.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
SELECT lines.geom
 FROM lines, polygons
 WHERE ST_Touches(lines.geom, polygons.geom) AND
                 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM polygons p2 WHERE ST_Crosses(lines.geom, p2.geom));
```

Comment: Does the `ST_Touches` compares any line to ant polygon?

Comment: I tried to explain more and added the change ST_Intersects -> ST_Crosses.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is what @Redoute wrote but change `ST_Intersects` to `ST_Crosses`. Because the blue line also intersects with polygon 2 when it touches him...